# JFrame doesn't conform JPanel's setMinimunSize()

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I expect `JPanel`'s `setMinimumSize()` to confine the resizing of `JFrame` too, but it doesn't.

The following is my example code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

public class AutoResize{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
        leftPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        rightPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        leftPanel.setSize(500,400);
        rightPanel.setSize(500,400);
        Dimension d = new Dimension(450,300);
        leftPanel.setMinimumSize(d);
        rightPanel.setMinimumSize(d);

        JSplitPane split;
        split = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, leftPanel, rightPanel);
        split.setDividerLocation(400);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(split, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(1000, 800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

If you resize `JFrame` into a very small size it produces this:
[image: weird behaviour]

What I want is that `JFrame` couldn't be resized into a smaller region than `JPanel`s' minimum size. Is there anyway to implement this?

Comment: The problem is, the JSplit can ignore the minimum size of component. Also, a frame is the preferred size of its content PLUS the frame decorations

Comment: *"I expect JPanel's setMinimumSize() confine resizing Jframe too but it didn't."*  After calling `pack()` call `frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getSize());` ..

Comment: @MadProgrammer By "*JSplit*" you mean "*JFrame*" I take it?

Comment: No, I was thinking about the `JSplitPane`

Comment: @MadProgrammer But the `JSplitPane` honors the minimum size of the components within it. Even if you remove it in this example and just put 1 panel in the frame, the frame will still not honor the minimum size of the panel.

Comment: @AndrewThompson i get your code's intention but it result in [this](http://i.imgur.com/Dd9Ss59.png?1). I assumes `frame.pack()` packed `jsplitpane` which has no dimension so it didn't work out.

Comment: But it doesn't mean the JSplitPane will continue to honor that up the container hierarchy. Preferred/minimum/maximum size are just hints which various layout managers can ignore

Comment: adding `split.setSize(1000,800);` doesn't work either

Comment: @MadProgrammer But in this case the `JSplitPane` seems to have nothing to do with the problem mentioned. In this case it does honor the minimum size while the frame (with or without the split pane) doesn't. (Also, you will want to use @ if you reply to me directly.)

Comment: @user1803551 But you seen to think that there is a direct relationship between the panel and the frame, when the relationship is managed through the layout manager which can ignore any of the siding hints

Comment: @LOKCARD Why not set the minimum size of the `frame` to `d`?

Comment: @user1803551 do u mean sum up left/right panel's dimension and set it into Jframe ? In other word : 500 + 500 width , 400 + 400 height , so `frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1000,800));` ?

Comment: thanks you all , I found a solution. Not sure if it follows the norm but at least it works as my expectation.

Answer (score 0):

All I need is adding `frame.setMinimumSize();` , I feel dumb.

Thanks @Andrew Thompson @MadProgrammer and @user1803551

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

public class AutoResize{

    private final Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    private final double w = screenSize.getWidth();
    private final double h = screenSize.getHeight();
    private final Dimension d = new Dimension((int) w/3,(int) h/3);

    public void run() {
        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
        leftPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        rightPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        //leftPanel.setSize(500,400);
        //rightPanel.setSize(500,400);
        leftPanel.setMinimumSize(d);
        rightPanel.setMinimumSize(d);

        JSplitPane split;
        split = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, leftPanel, rightPanel);
        split.setDividerLocation(400);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(split, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setSize((int) w,(int) h);
        //frame.pack();
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension((int) w/3*2,(int) h/3*2));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AutoResize test = new AutoResize();
        test.run();
    }
}
```